# Blender game engine graphics

Tags: game-engine

I know this may be a stupid question but how do I make the background look more realistic or 3d like [image]

here is the game file http://www.pasteall.org/blend/37831

Comment: 1. You should pack the textures into the blend file. Right now, none of the textures are available, because they are only on your computer.   2.Could you be more specific about what you are trying to do? You can make the building look more realistic, by:  using a different texture; using more than one background and employing some parallax effect; actually using 3d buildings to create the background plane.   It's a little hard to see what style your going after with the mix of soft, round-character, and hard-edged, pixelated bg art.

Comment: How about using 3D objects as background?

Comment: if your wallpaper has no movement, you could use a normal map to give it a touch of relief, or if you want it to be animated, you could try using sprites to animate the texture, ammm I would lower it specular to 0 in the character see that flash white on the helmet does not look very attractive visually